# Java Configuration equivalent of <jdbc-user-service> in Spring Security

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-security, spring-java-config, xml-configuration

When we use xml based configuration for Spring Security we are able to use `<jdbc-user-service>` tag with attributes `authorities-by-username-query` and `users-by-username-query` to get username, password and role from database for a specific username input.

Reference:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-jdbc-user-service

The code given in Spring Security documentation for Java Configuration seem to be using hard-coded username & password.

Reference:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc

The related sample project (spring-security / samples / **jdbc-jc**) also appears to use the same hard-coded username & password values.

So with Java Configuration, how can we validate the user input with user credentials stored in a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [JdbcDaoImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) class with his setters [setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html#setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(java.lang.String)) and [setUsersByUsernameQuery()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html#setUsersByUsernameQuery(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!